# Q: I can't understand "var variable = {" in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, user-agent

I'm modifying the jQuery source code which another person has programmed.

But there was a var definition which I can't understand.

I had no idea about this code, so I googled and searching, but couldn't find any answers.

js

```
var isMobile = {
  Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
    BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
    iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  },
    Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
    Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
  },
    any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
  }
};
```

I want to know what does this code mean.

Also, I'd like to know the syntax, such as

js

```
 var isMobile = {
   Android: function() {
     return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
 },
```

What `Android:` means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is defining an object and assigning it to a variable named “isMobile”.

“Android” is a property of that object, and its value is a function.

The function performs a test on the browser’s user agent string to determine whether it is running in an android browser.

All of this together allows other code to determine whether it’s running in an android browser by calling `isMobile.Android()`.

Or iOS by calling `isMobile.iOS()`, and so on.

`isMobile.any()` iterates over the other functions, invoking them to see if *any* of them are true; so if you want to know if you’re running on a mobile device but don’t care specifically which kind, you’d use this.

---

Every browser provides a variable called `navigator` that contains information about the browser, including a `userAgent` property that gives clues about which browser and version it is. I'm running Brave, and here's what `navigator` looks like for me. I've highlighted the `userAgent` part.

[image: Brave navigator screenshot]

`userAgent` values can be kind of infuriating. I'm running Brave but the userAgent string mentions Mozilla, Gecko, Chrome, and Safari. Ugh. But that's a whole other can of worms.

As I said, you can look for clues about what browser you're running in this value. To do so, this code is using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Regular expressions are a powerful pattern-matching syntax used to find substrings or patterns within strings. Far too complicated for me to explain in detail here, but as an example, the expression `userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)` is looking for any of the words "iPhone", "iPad", or "iPod" in the `userAgent` value. (The part between the slashes is the pattern, and the trailing `i` is a flag to make the search case-insensitive.)

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`isMobile` is returning an object with key-value pairs. The keys are, e.g. `Android`, and `Blackberry`, and their values are basically methods/functions that are only invoked when you try to access them. E.g. by invoking `isMobile.Android()` will actually invoke the function and check if the user agent matches a string of your choice.

You can see `isMobile` as an object with methods accessible by keys, which you can call to check if the browser's user agents matches certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates "isMobile" object and declares functions to check the kind of mobile browser. Check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp for creating objects in JavaScript.

To explain following piece of code:

```
    var isMobile = {
  Android: function() {
    return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  }
```

- isMobile is a JavaScript object.
- Andorid is a property of "isMobile" object. This property check whether the browser being used to navigate the web page is "Android browser". "window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)" this part in code returns true if the browser is "Andorid" browser.